# capacitor charging to over specified voltage

Tags: voltage, capacitor, charging

Can i charge in real circuit any capacitor, that is **rated to 2.7** V to **input voltage 12 V**   as shown in the picture?

I mean regular charging and discharging.
The current through capacitor will never exceed 12V(input DC voltage)/500Ohm (series resistance )

Regards and thanks.

---

By the way : found this text :

"The voltage rating is only the maximum voltage that a capacitor should be exposed to, not the voltage that the capacitor will charge up to. A capacitor will only charge to a specific voltage level if fed that level of voltage from a DC power source."

from :

http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/What-does-the-voltage-rating-on-a-capacitor-mean

Can you confirm!

---

[image]

sorry. this is the principal scheme.

Comment: Probably once before you hear it go BANG!

Comment: Sure you can then wait a while and it might explode.

Comment: Shown in what picture? You haven't added one in the question.

Comment: How much higher you can charge than the rated voltage (before damage) depends a lot on the type of capacitor.  Ceramics tend to be more forgiving than aluminum electrolytics for example.  Don't try this at home as you're risking an explosion.  Why not just get a cap rated for the proper voltage?  If size is the issue remember that you're dealing with the laws of physics.....

Answer (score 5):

Those 2V7 supercaps use a wet electrolyte, which will break down quickly once the voltage is over spec - in your case 2.7 volts. The cap will either open its vent or (in rare cases) explode due to excessive internal pressure. In both cases it will no longer be usable.